click listener of an html option element
I am trying to assign an click eventlistener to a html option element, I want to display the time picker in a task management project using HTML,CSS and vanilla JAVA-SCRIPT by selecting a choose-date option,How can i resolve this issue using only simple Java-Script?
Here my code:


const chooseDate = document.getElementById("choose-date");
chooseDate.addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.getElementById("date").classList.remove("hidden");
});
body {
  background-color: rgb(143, 134, 134);
}

input,
select {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 50%;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

input {
  bottom: 45%;
  display: none;
}
<select name="selection" id="my-selection">
  <option value="today">today</option>
  <option value="tomorrow">tomorrow</option>
  <option value="choose-date">choose-date</option>
</select>
<input type="datetime-local" name="" id="" />




How is your code not performing as expected? Have you checked your dev console for errors?

I don't think click listeners work on <option>. You can use a change listener on the <select> and have it check if they've selected this option.

I'm pretty sure options don't emit clicks, but this code won't work for a couple of other reasons...not least of which being, your option and date input don't have the ids you're looking for...

You'll want to attach the event listener to the <select> element and handle the visibility of the date picker based on the selected option. Here's how you can adjust your code:

Assign an ID to the input element: This makes it easier to select and manipulate the date picker input with JavaScript.

Change the Event Listener: Instead of adding the event listener to an option (which doesn't work as options don’t handle events directly), attach it to the  element and listen for change events.

Update the JavaScript to toggle visibility: Check the value of the selected option in the event listener and toggle the visibility of the date picker accordingly.


It should look something like this:
HTML:
<select name="selection" id="my-selection">
  <option value="today">Today</option>
  <option value="tomorrow">Tomorrow</option>
  <option value="choose-date">Choose Date</option>
</select>
<input type="datetime-local" id="date-picker" style="display: none;" />

JS:
document.getElementById("my-selection").addEventListener("change", function() {
  var datePicker = document.getElementById("date-picker");
  if (this.value === "choose-date") {
    datePicker.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    datePicker.style.display = "none";
  }
});


There is no element with an id of 'choose-date'. For the getElementById to work you will need to set the id of one of the elements to 'choose-date'.
<option value="choose-date" id="choose-date">choose-date</option>


The "id" should be on the select, not the option.
